# Is it safe to use an output (to_char) date format string of more than 22 characters (ORACLE 11)

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, date-format

The ORACLE SQL manual (Page 2-58 of the main 11.1 SQL Manual) states:

> The total length of a datetime format model cannot exceed 22 characters.

However, I've been able to use a format string for TO_CHAR with many more characters, almost all of which are text "literals".

Is this safe (ORACLE 11)? (Perhaps the limit does not include non-date literals?)

For example:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate,
       '"SOMESTRING_"YYYYMMDD"_SOME LOTS MORE STRINGS OF A FILENAME PREFIX"') 
FROM DUAL;
```

Result:

```
SOMESTRING_20200226_SOME LOTS MORE STRINGS OF A FILENAME PREFIX
```

It also works with dates from tables.

The reason I want to do this is to build a filename template in a database column; otherwise I will need to put the date format in a separate field.

P.S. Please tell me if this should be asked in a different community. I've never asked a question before, so I have no reputation to lose :-). Be nice.

Comment: Link to the online manual would be nice.

Comment: `It also works with dates from tables.` You put in gibberish and you get out gibberish (aka [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out)). As far as I'm concerned what you've done should throw an error - but hey, that's Oracle's problem! `otherwise I will need to put the date format in a separate field.` **IF** it's a date, then it belongs in a date column - otherwise you'll spend a lot of time parsing strings - which is **NOT** what SQL was designed for! p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Comment: @/v%c3%a9race I'm not sure what you meant by gibberish. Yes, I realized the alternative is to use a format in a separate column and use replace; I was trying to keep the question short.  In fact, the actual template is more like %PCNAMEYYMMDD_RESTOFNAME, with REPLACE used to repalce %P with another database field. Also, I didn't want to be too specific for proprietary reasons. And no, I'm not storing any new dates, just the template of the filename. (Thank you for the welcome!)

Comment: So - the answer is, don't take a chance. Understood.

Comment: @Verace Sorry, I was trying to get the accent in your name, and now it won't let me edit. Also, sorry everyone for all of the comments.

Comment: It appears to work without accents! "Gibberish" is rubbish or garbage - except it is more spoken rubbish or garbage, so technically, my English was flawed! But, I still say that you should extract that date **AS A DATE** and then, should you need to, appending it as a string to other strings should be relatively easy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you can jump off a cliff, doesn't mean you should.

Use [`REPLACE()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm) with a token:

```
select REPLACE('SOMESTRING_##DATE##_SOME LOTS MORE STRINGS OF A FILENAME PREFIX',
               '##DATE##',
               TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD'))
from DUAL;
```

You could take this a step further to allow different format strings:

```
with mytable as (
select 'SOMESTRING_##YYYYMMDD##_SOME LOTS MORE STRINGS OF A FILENAME PREFIX' as format_string
from DUAL
)
select REGEXP_REPLACE(format_string,'##(.*)##',TO_CHAR(sysdate,replace(
                    regexp_substr( format_string, '##(.*)##', 1, 1),'##','')))
  from mytable;
```

Note that there have been parsing bugs with long `TO_CHAR` identifiers that have caused ORA-600 errors & session crashes.

Comment: @Boneist read the question. "The reason I want to do this is to build a filename template in a database column; otherwise I will need to put the date format in a separate field." -- the OP wants to store a format string in a single column

Comment: Ah, I missed that bit! D'oh!

Comment: @Phil Thank you. So, I'll use one column for the template and one for the date format, and use REPLACE. That was the alternative I intended.

Answer (score -1):

I would use this one instead:

```
SELECT 'SOMESTRING_' || TO_CHAR(sysdate,'YYYYMMDD') || '_SOME LOTS MORE STRINGS OF A FILENAME PREFIX'
FROM DUAL;
```